# WSARecv takes around 3 seconds to execute in socket programmng windows?

Tags: c++

How can i improve the performance of WSARecv to complete as fast as possible. IT uses a overlapped and a blocking socket.
The code is as below.

```
WSARecv(*socket, &Buffer, 1, &RecvCount, &Flag, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the socket is blocking, my guess is that remote end isn't sending anything, and `WSARecv` is *blocking* while waiting for data to arrive.

Oh, and from the [`WSARecv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) manual page:

```
If both lpOverlapped and lpCompletionRoutine are NULL, the socket in this
function will be treated as a nonoverlapped socket.
```

This means that while the socket may be overlapped, this call will not treat it as such, since both of those pointers are NULL. You should either make use of non-blocking sockets, or use overlapping, but not both.

Comment: ok, if i make a socket non blocking, will there be a problem for sending and receiving?

Comment: @Ershad Edited my answer. I suggest you read the referenced manual page and use overlapped sockets properly and the call wont block anymore.

Comment: Sorry , i got it now. Let me check.

Comment: @Ershad That error is WSAEWOULDBLOCK, means that the call would block, and that you should try again a little later. The link is in my answer.